# Kendo chart stack bar to multi series

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

I have a chart with stack bar.
[image]

http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/OsaVE.

Instead of the stack, how can i show in the bar series...

similar like this [image]

Comment: Anyone explain me, why i got negative points  for this question ?  The question is valid one... its really strange

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Finally lot of struggle, i found the solution**

[jsbin working example](http://jsbin.com/dovefikohu/edit?html,js,output)

```
 $("#chart").kendoChart({
  seriesDefaults: {
    type: "column"
  },
  series: [{
    name: "Sales",
    data: [10, 20, 0.5, 0, 100, 0]
  }],
  valueAxis: [{
    majorGridLines: { visible: false },
    title: { text: "Sales" },
    axisCrossingValue: [0,0]
  }],
  categoryAxis: [{
    categories: ["Order", "Invoice", "Credit Memo", "Order", "Invoice", "Credit Memo"],
    majorGridLines: { visible: false }
  },
                 {
    categories: ["Item", "Resources"],
    line: { visible: true },
    majorGridLines: { visible: true },
    title: { text: "Type & Document Type" }
  }
                ]
});
```

Comment: Anyone explain me, why i got negative points ? .... After sharing the expected also getting negative points... what is things going on ?